# How did Dr. Mann recognise that Yorick had a Y chromosome?

Tags: y-the-last-man

In episode 5, Mann Hunt, Yorick and Agent 355 meet up with the Harvard geneticist Dr. Alison Mann. She initially attacks them, but on seeing Yorick’s face she is shocked and asks “you got a Y chromosome, don’t you?”.

This almost sounds like an awkwardly-written “sciency” way of asking “you’re a man, aren’t you?”, but both the show in general and the character of Dr. Mann specifically are aware that transgender and intersex people exist. Not long after, Mann gives a whole monologue about how “man” and “person with a Y chromosome” aren’t the same thing. Is she just jumping to the correct conclusion about why these people are looking for her, or is there some sort of clue in the scene that she picks up on?

Comment: Well, although being a man, having a "masculine appearance", and having a Y chromosome are indeed certainly *not* the same thing, they *are* highly correlated (as in, probably over 95%), and most people who look like they have a Y chromosome do. Is it possible that the scientist is just thinking that Yorick *probably* has a Y chromosome, without ruling out the possibility that he may not?

Comment: @Adamant You're right that those things are highly correlated now, in a world where the three groups each make up around half the population, but after seemingly all and certainly the vast majority of humans with Y chromosomes are killed you need to adjust your priors somewhat. Trans men and masculine-looking cis women are far more common than cis men in the setting.

Comment: True enough. In that case, perhaps her profession gave her a clue (i.e. they were looking for a geneticist, so they might have a reason). Alternately, was she born back when there *were* a lot more people with Y chromosomes around? If so, she may be reasoning from her previous priors without adequately having adjusted her reasoning to the new situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not explained in the episode, but my best guess is that like you said she correctly surmised why these people were looking for her. If Dr. Mann had seen Yorick in the street she would have been very unlikely to make the leap of logic required, and if she thought about him at all would likely have assumed he was either a trans man or one of the rare cis men born without a Y chromosome, but when he and Agent 355 show up there is clearly *something* going on.

A federal agent, on orders from the President, has travelled to a lawless city in a different state looking for one particular geneticist (who I assume specialises in something related to the Y chromosome given that she was on the shortlist). Tagging along with her is some guy who doesn't act like a federal agent and wasn't identified as one, the best guess is that 355 is escorting him to her.

So if Dr. Mann realises that Yorick is being brought to her with some urgency, then there's obviously something very important about him, and there's only one major event on everyone's mind right now. From this point it's not too much of a leap to guess that they've found someone immune to whatever just happened.

Answer (score 3):

Dr. Mann is a Harvard geneticist. She knows in great detail the distinctions between gender and sex, as well as features of cis vs. transgender and intersex individuals.

She based her hypothesis that Yorick has a Y-chromosome on her extensive knowledge of genetic karotypes.

She asked the question because she was in a state of disbelief at meeting a mammal with a Y-chromosome because all them were believed to have died with the cataclysm.

She asked her question in form of chromosomes because that is her scientific speciality, and that is also the nature of the premise of the show: that all mammals with Y-chromosomes (except Y) are dead.

In short: she was being technically precise because she is a scientist who specializes in the subject matter of the question.